# Can Untangle be installed to a partition?

Tags: untangle

Skim reading the Untangle website last night I was left with the impression that Untangle will wipe an entire disk on install. I have an XP notebook that I was going to use as a gateway to a home LAN.

I like the idea of a UTM but I'd also like to be able to keep my Xp box... for whatever reason. Plenty of space on the drive tho so figured I would compress existing partitions, make some room for Untangle  and install to a partition.

Can this be done?

If not why? Is it just a limitation of the install GUI or a deliberate decision to require nothing but Untangle running on some hardware, for security reasons.

Comment: You are aware that you couldn't run Untangle and the XP partition at the same time, correct?

Comment: Yes. I have an XP "setup", that I want left in place for any "emergency". I'd prefer to have it on disk and boot into it as / if ever necessary rather than having to ghost it to back up and ghost back etc. It'd be there for convenience..... one which i have needed at least twice in the last 18 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [wiki](http://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/Untangle_Deployments), the only way to install with another OS is to virtualize the Untangle install.

As for why, I would assume it's because of the nature of the system.  This is a router/bridge replacement, which would be a kind of "install and never touch again" setup.

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer as it's "the only way" but note for anyone choosing this route there are minimum hardware requirements for the VMWare Player which is required in order to host Untangle. This meant i couldn't actually use this method because my old Xp box while perfectly fine for just Untangle does not meet the VMWare Player hardware requirements i.e. 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Untangle wiki:

Can I install Untangle on a dual boot machine?

No. Untangle is designed to run on a dedicated computer. Booting to an Untangle or non-Untangle partition would also imply different network configurations depending on how the machine was booted. If you don't have a spare computer available, consider installing Untangle as a virtual appliance under VMWare.